# Writing to file in netBeans IDE in java

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public class FileWriterClass {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
    br.write("helllllllllllllllll");

  }    
}
```

its not writing into file.please help me out

Comment: you need to close the the writer aswell.

Comment: The writer will not flush the data to the file unless you close it all again, you seem to be missing some code from whatever example you are following.

Comment: [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should always call the `close()` once you finish writing the data.

```
public class FileWriterClass {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
    br.write("helllllllllllllllll");
    br.close();
    fr.close();
  }    
}
```

Comment: And if an exception is thrown before the `close` statements are called?

Comment: just use `try{//some code} catch{//some code} finally{br.close(); fr.close();} `

Comment: @alias_boubou You're assuming that `br` and `fr` are not `null` and won't throw an `Exception` when `close` is called

Comment: you're right, we need to check nullability of br and fr in if statement before  the close method

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the writers are closed, which will flush the buffer to disk.  You need to do this because Java makes no guarentees that the objects will be finalised and closed automatically.

To make life easier for yourself, you can make use of the [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which will close the writers automatically, even if there is an exception during the write process

```
public class FileWriterClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
                BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fr)) {
            br.write("helllllllllllllllll");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `close()` the `BufferedWriter` and `FileWriter`  like this:

```
   br.write("helllllllllllllllll");
   br.close();
   fr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not Closing the Resources That's why it write Continuous.
and must have to put risky code inside `Try catch` block. must have to use `close` and `flush` the File Operation
**Updated Code** : -

```
public class FileWriterClass {
public static void main(String[] args){
try{
FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
br.write("helllllllllllllllll");
br.close();
}catch(IOException i){
i.printStackTrace();
}}}
```

Comment: And if an exception is thrown before the `close` statements are called?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the utility methods of [java.lang.nio.file.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). Which removes the need to write to much boilerplate code.

```
public class FileWriterClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // path to the file to write, in this case the file
        // will be created in the current directory
        Path path = Paths.get("hello.txt");

        // the character set of the file
        Charset fileCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        // the needed code to write to the file
        try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, fileCharset)) {
            bw.write("hello NIO 2");
        }        
    }

}
```